# Get data from script tag with Scrapy Xpath and using it as CSV

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to extract data from script tag using Scrapy(xpath). My main issue is with identifying the correct div and script tags. I'm new to using xpath and would be thankful for any kind of help!

```
<script>    
var COUNTRY_SHOP_STATUS = "buy";
var COUNTRY_SHOP_URL = "";
try {
digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_2 = "mobile";
digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_3 = "mobile";
digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_4 = "smartphones";
digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_5 = "galaxy-s8";    
digitalData.product.pvi_type_name = "Mobile";
digitalData.product.pvi_subtype_name = "Smartphone";
digitalData.product.model_name = "SM-G950F";
digitalData.product.category = digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_3;
} catch(e) {}
</script>
```

I would finally like to populate my csv file with the data of model.name and depth 3, 4 and 5. I've tried the other solutions from the questions similar to this one but they seem to not work...

Comment: could you provde a sample of the data you are trying to extract information from?

Comment: *"I've tried the other solutions..."* Which solutions exactly? Share current and desired output

Comment: @Ggg Thank you for your answer! So the url I'm trying to access is this one: https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-s8/ . This is only for Galaxy S8, but I need to access the other ones too. Galaxy S9, Note 9 etc. I want to retrive the following data from that script tag: I want to take the values such: "Smartphone", "galaxy-s9","mobile" from those variables like digitalData.product.pvi_subtype_name = "Smartphone"; or digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_5 = "galaxy-s8"; and I want to store these values in a CSV file.

Comment: @Andersson Thank you for your answer too! I've looked on the following topics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721021/get-data-from-script-tag-with-scrapy-xpath  AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871064/python-scrapy-get-html-script-tag. I've edited the solutions presented there but they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex` to extract required values:

```
import re

source = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'COUNTRY_SHOP_STATUS')]/text()").extract()[0]

def get_values(parameter, script):
    return re.findall('%s = "(.*)"' % parameter, script)[0]

print(get_values("pathIndicator.depth_5", source))
print(get_values("pvi_subtype_name", source))
print(get_values("model_name", source))
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Andersson! It works like a charm! Thanks a lot!! How can I store the values printed by those "print" functions in a CSV directly from the terminal? Have a beautiful day!

Comment: You can save required values [into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642082/convert-txt-to-csv-python-script). Don't forget to [mark the answer as "Accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your issue