# How to change style attribute's value in a div tag in scraping process, with scrapy?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

So, my issue is from a specific tag in a webpage which hides the content I want to scrape.

[Here the link of the page](https://www.zeturf.fr/fr/course/2018-10-19/R1C1-vincennes-prix-klymene/turf)

Let's show you what I exactly expect to scrape.

Due to my non possiblity to insert image, because I miss reputation for it... I give you some links to images host.

[image]
You can see in this one, the tab "COTES" content is actually hidden in the html render as you can see in the redbox.

But I noticed that if I change in `< div id="pariCotesTab" class="tab" style="display: none;"` the attribute `style` to `style="display: block;"`, the hidden html part is appearing: [you can see it in the second image](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=18/44/t7p7.png).

When I use `scrapy shell https://www.zeturf.fr/fr/course/2018-10-19/R1C1-vincennes-prix-klymene/turf` and try to get an element of the "COTES" tab, for instance `In [1]: response.xpath("//td[@class='cote-simplegagnant cote-reference']/text()").extract()` , it returns nothing `Out 1: []`, which is logical but it blocks me.

So how it is possible to change the attribute `style` to `style="display: block;"` in a scrapy process? and to obtain what I want to scrape in the "COTES" tab.

I would like to mention, I prefer don't use splash because it was an hell for me with docker installation and so on... I **won't** use selenium, because I want to scrape about 1000 pages, maybe more. I used selenium for a previous project, and the webdriving with any browser is just a waste of time for scraping. That is a webtester above all, not a webcrawler and not a webscraper module.

Scrapy version: 1.5.0, Python version: 2.7.9

Comment: Which elements exactly are you trying to scrape with that xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not what you have assumed it is.

Scrapy doesn't care what css styles are used (unless you explicitly use them in your selectors), only about what is present in the page's source.
The source of your page contains something like this:

```html
<th class="cote-simplegagnant cote-reference"></th>
```

As you can see, the `th`s you're selecting are empty, and they are being populated later by javascript.
Taking a closer look at the source, you can find a `script` tag containing the info you want:

```js
cotesInfos: {"referenceDateTime":{"date":"2018-10-19 19:30:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"},"meilleureCoteSG":{"reference":3.3,"live":3.6},"displayedColumns":{"hasSG":1,"hasSP":1,"hasZC":1,"hasZS":1},"1":{"odds_single":27.2,"odds_couillon":11.7,"odds_zeshow":29,"odds":{"reference":36.4,"SG":27.2,"SPMin":5,"SPMax":9.1,"ZC":11.7,"ZS":29},"oddsprogress_single":"moins"},"2":{"odds_single":13.3,"odds_couillon":13.6,"odds_zeshow":11.4,"odds":{"reference":14.5,"SG":13.3,"SPMin":2.3,"SPMax":4.1,"ZC":13.6,"ZS":11.4}},"3":{"odds_single":3.7,"odds_couillon":7.2,"odds_zeshow":8,"odds":{"reference":6.8,"SG":3.7,"SPMin":1.2,"SPMax":1.8,"ZC":7.2,"ZS":8},"oddsprogress_single":"moins"},"4":{"odds_single":274.1,"odds_couillon":19.6,"odds_zeshow":40.9,"odds":{"reference":168.9,"SG":274.1,"SPMin":13.5,"SPMax":41.7,"ZC":19.6,"ZS":40.9},"oddsprogress_single":"plus"},"5":{"odds_single":20.2,"odds_couillon":9,"odds_zeshow":13.1,"odds":{"reference":16,"SG":20.2,"SPMin":2.9,"SPMax":5.2,"ZC":9,"ZS":13.1},"oddsprogress_single":"plus"},"6":{"odds_single":9.4,"odds_couillon":11.7,"odds_zeshow":12.6,"odds":{"reference":4.8,"SG":9.4,"SPMin":3.2,"SPMax":5.8,"ZC":11.7,"ZS":12.6},"oddsprogress_single":"plus"},"7":{"odds_single":32.3,"odds_couillon":9.8,"odds_zeshow":11.4,"odds":{"reference":27.9,"SG":32.3,"SPMin":5.1,"SPMax":9.2,"ZC":9.8,"ZS":11.4},"oddsprogress_single":"plus"},"8":{"odds_single":78.2,"odds_couillon":16.3,"odds_zeshow":34.8,"odds":{"reference":109.3,"SG":78.2,"SPMin":8,"SPMax":14.7,"ZC":16.3,"ZS":34.8},"oddsprogress_single":"moins"},"9":{"odds_single":7.1,"odds_couillon":9.9,"odds_zeshow":9.5,"odds":{"reference":11.2,"SG":7.1,"SPMin":1.5,"SPMax":2.5,"ZC":9.9,"ZS":9.5},"oddsprogress_single":"moins"},"10":{"odds_single":3.6,"odds_couillon":18.9,"odds_zeshow":2.9,"odds":{"reference":3.3,"SG":3.6,"SPMin":1.6,"SPMax":2.7,"ZC":18.9,"ZS":2.9}},"11":{"odds_single":16.4,"odds_couillon":9.6,"odds_zeshow":13.1,"odds":{"reference":14.4,"SG":16.4,"SPMin":3.4,"SPMax":6,"ZC":9.6,"ZS":13.1},"oddsprogress_single":"plus"},"12":{"odds_single":21.3,"odds_couillon":6.7,"odds_zeshow":10,"odds":{"reference":23.3,"SG":21.3,"SPMin":3.8,"SPMax":6.8,"ZC":6.7,"ZS":10}},"13":{"odds_single":40.9,"odds_couillon":21,"odds_zeshow":27.8,"odds":{"reference":20.1,"SG":40.9,"SPMin":5.8,"SPMax":10.6,"ZC":21,"ZS":27.8},"oddsprogress_single":"plus"},"14":{"odds_single":34.8,"odds_couillon":10.8,"odds_zeshow":20.4,"odds":{"reference":22.2,"SG":34.8,"SPMin":5.2,"SPMax":9.5,"ZC":10.8,"ZS":20.4},"oddsprogress_single":"plus"}}
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. I used the firefox console and I found what you showed me. I put the link in my browser : https://www.zeturf.fr/js/e4f443e.js?v326. I don't know why, when I am on this page the odds are not present. They are only in my firefox console. I don't know how it exactly works honestly.

Answer (score 0):

So grace to the answer of stranac I found what I needed.
Here you can see in the inspector the "COTES" tab in the html in a `<script` tag.
[image: Here the odds to scrap in a script tag of the html]
Whit the `odds_raw = response.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']").extract()[6]` I get what I want. But it is kinda raw. So I used the advice of Micheal Yin in a tutorial you can consult [here](https://blog.michaelyin.info/scrapy-tutorial-11-how-to-extract-data-from-native-javascript-statement/). And here another example on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871064/python-scrapy-get-html-script-tag).

So with the command `odds = re.search('({"referenceDateTime")(.*?)(\\n)', odds_raw).group()` I got this

```
Out[65]: u'{"referenceDateTime":{"date":"2018-10-19 19:30:00.000000","timezone_t
ype":3,"timezone":"Europe\\/Paris"},"meilleureCoteSG":{"reference":3.3,"live":3.
6},"displayedColumns":{"hasSG":1,"hasSP":1,"hasZC":1,"hasZS":1},"1":{"odds_singl
e":27.2,"odds_couillon":11.7,"odds_zeshow":29,"odds":{"reference":36.4,"SG":27.2
,"SPMin":5,"SPMax":9.1,"ZC":11.7,"ZS":29},"oddsprogress_single":"moins"}...}}\n'
```

Now I use the `json.loads` function, `json.loads(odds)` then I got a python dictionnary.